# Estimate remaining time to failure based only on average time to failure

Tags: probability, survival, conditional-probability, mortality

Suppose a random variable X representing time to failure. I don't know its pdf and only know its E[X]. How can I derive E[ X | X > t], i.e. average remaining time to failure? If it is impossible to do so without knowing its pdf, is it possible to come up with a decent estimate based on the knowledge of E[X] only. Human life expectancy is a concrete example of this problem. Given that the life expectancy = 75, is it possible to get a decent estimate for how much longer a person aged 80 can live?

A graph below is plotted on the data points sampled from X. It shows the shape of X density function. It always is left skewed and have a right long tail.

[image]

Comment: I think you need to know something about the shape of the survival curve to get a decent answer.

Comment: @M.Austin I attached the shape of X distribution above.

Comment: Do any cases never fail over the observation time of about 750000 units? Have some cases just not failed yet at times less than that? Those would be considered "censored," an issue raised in the answer by @M.Austin. If there are "censored" cases in that sense then knowing the distribution of failure times only for cases that failed does not tell you the distribution of failure times  among all cases.

Comment: @M.Austin I created another related post: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444259/estimating-survival-time-given-a-set-of-data-points-for-cdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel like I might need more detail, but I going to make some assumptions here. If they are wrong please correct me and I will change my answer or delete it so I do not confuse anybody.

When you say "shape of X", I assume you mean it is a density function. Therefore, you should first create an empirical survival function for the purpose of my explanation. Please note that there are many ways to approach this. I am trying to offer a very straight forward way of doing it.

To create the survival curve, calculate 1 minus the empirical cumulative distribution function. Then you should have a graph (assuming no censoring) that starts at $S(0)=1$ and goes to $S(\infty)=0$ and is monotonically decreasing as "t" gets large.

So generally speaking the integral of the survival function is the actual mean survival time of the distribution. Therefore I would write out the conditional mean as follows:

$$E(T|T>t) = \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{S(x)}{S(t)} dx $$

where $S(t) = P(T > t)$ is the unconditional survival curve. So just take the graph above and apply a numerical integration function to it from any "t" to $\infty$ (or pick a really large number as the integral's upper bound instead of using infinity) and divide this integral by the survival curve's value at "t" (i.e. S(t)).

Then store this value in a vector for each value of "t" and loop over as many values of "t" that you want and you have a nice graph of the conditional mean for every value of "t". If you wanted just an expected value for a single "t", then you are all set. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the kind answer! The above graph is plotted from the data points sampled from X. So actually I know 2 piece of information here: mean of X and sampling distribution. Could you suggest how to model the X density function based on mean of X and the sampling distribution(shape of X)? I assume once I can model the density function of X and then I can just follow your method to derive average remaining time.

Comment: @taichuang you need to decide whether to use the empirical data directly or try to model those empirical data with a particular functional form. If you use the empirical data directly, statistical software typically provides a way to get the empirical cumulative distribution function, for example the `ecdf()` function in R. With a modeled functional form, you would use the resulting modeled form of the cumulative distribution function. With either the empirical or modeled cumulative distribution you would follow the steps indicated in this (+1) answer.

Comment: @EdM I am looking for a parametric model to model X's density function. It will just need to convert the mean of X into the parameter values. I am thinking if gamma distribution can work for my problem.

Comment: If you decide to use a parametric model, then I think you are all set, as if there is a closed form solution to your expected value. That said, try a goodness of fit test for your data on any distribution that you are thinking of to be sure.

Comment: @taichuang I would recommend using statistical software that fits survival data directly, like the `survreg()` function in the R [survival package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=survival), rather than fitting the data yourself. Software for survival analysis deals with the censored cases for which no failures have been recorded yet; ignoring censoring will get you into trouble. A [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution) is often used for failure-time analysis and has a simple closed-form expression for its survival function, unlike the gamma distribution.