# Estimating Survival Time Given A Set of Data Points for CDF

Tags: probability, survival, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Suppose I have a set of data points to describe a cdf(cumulative density function) for X: for example, (cumulative probability, x): (0.3, 100), (0.5, 200), (0.9, 400), (0.95, 800), (0.99, 1000). How to use this information to compute the survival time for X, i.e. E[X | X > t]?

Comment: Unless you have data going out all the way to a cumulative probability of 1, you can't get a unique solution for E[X | X > t] based on observations alone. For example, with your data how would you deal with times t > 1000? You would have to model with some distribution (and hope that you modeled extreme times correctly). Also, as this is related to your [other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/444098/28500) you must make sure to deal with any "censored" cases that did not fail during the time of observation. More details on how you will use the results of your model would help.

Comment: It should be possible to put a lower bound on the expected value of the curtate survival time.